# I don´t work well javascript in datetable

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc

At my app I´m using datetable for to represent dynamic tables, and I have developed some function in javascript to catch dates of a row when user make click with a mouse in a row.
It makes it well in the first page but the next pages doesn´t make it well, if I make click in some row, event doesn´t work.
When I also push about header column to order then in the first rows don´t work.
An example:
[image]

[image]

[image]

The code is next:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".rowClick").click(function(){
     alert($(this).text());
   });
   $(".rowClick").mouseenter(function(){
     $(this).css("background-color", "#CCC");
   });
   $(".rowClick").mouseleave(function(){
     $(this).css("background-color", "#f6f6f6");
   });
});
</script>
...
    <table id="tablePrueba">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><fmt:message key="common.mac"/></th>
                    <th><fmt:message key="common.model"/></th>
                    <th><fmt:message key="common.maker"/></th>
                    <th><fmt:message key="common.serialNumber"/></th>
                    <th><fmt:message key="common.vendor"/></th>
                    <th><fmt:message key="common.purchase"/></th>
                    <th><fmt:message key="common.warranty"/></th>
                    <th><fmt:message key="common.manufacturer"/></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="rowClick">
                    <td>1234:5678</td>
                    <td>model1</td>
                    <td>maker1</td>
                    <td>0123456789</td>
                    <td>vendor1</td>
                    <td>26/11/2013</td>
                    <td>26/11/2015</td>
                    <td>manufacturer1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="rowClick">
                    <td>8765:4321</td>
                    <td>model2</td>
                    <td>maker2</td>
                    <td>9876543210</td>
                    <td>vendor2</td>
                    <td>01/01/2013</td>
                    <td>01/01/2015</td>
                    <td>manufacturer2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="rowClick">
                    <td>0000:1111</td>
                    <td>model3</td>
                    <td>maker3</td>
                    <td>1234567890</td>
                    <td>vendor3</td>
                    <td>01/01/2010</td>
                    <td>01/01/2012</td>
                    <td>manufacturer3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
```

What would it be that the next pages it also makes it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

`$(document).on(event, selector, handler).`

as in

`$(document).on("click", ".rowClick", function(){ alert($(this).text());});`

This will ensure the click event handler gets applied to all `.rowClick` rows created in the future as well.

Comment: Perfect. It works to the perfection!!. Thanks very much!! ;)